# How to put an alert in jquery to know if an event that you want to add is already in the database or has a conflicting schedule with other events?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jquery-mobile

I have a table of booked events in the db with date, event_name, venue, time_start and time_finish.
Now, when I want to book a new event, i want to check first if a certain venue is already occupied given a date and a time frame.

this is what i've got so far and it's not working.

```
<?php
session_start();
include('config1.php');

       $sql = "SELECT venue FROM schedules WHERE venue =".$_POST['venue']" && date =".$_POST['date']" ";

       $select = mysql_query($sql);

       $row = mysql_num_rows($select);

            if ($row > 0)  
          {
            echo 'true';  
          }
             else 
          {
             echo 'false';
          }

?>


and the check-venue.php
<?php
session_start();
include('config1.php');

       $sql = "SELECT venue FROM schedules WHERE venue =".$_POST['venue']" && date =".$_POST['date']" ";

       $select = mysql_query($sql);

       $row = mysql_num_rows($select);

            if ($row > 0)  
          {
            echo 'true';  
          }
             else 
          {
             echo 'false';
          }

?>
```

Comment: "it's not working" - please be more descriptive. Error messages, output vs expected output, etc.

Comment: it doesn't do anything but add the new event to the db. i want it to return an error message or a prompt saying that a certain venue is already booked.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you really shouldn't be using the `mysql_*` functions:

> This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in
>   the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

Secondly, by putting `$_POST` values directly in the query like that you are opening yourself up to all sorts of injection attacks. You need to make sure that you are escaping any data properly to prevent that.

Thirdly (and presumably why it's not working at all), you are not quoting the (presumably string) values you are sending to the DB, and there are syntax errors when you're building your query - you are missing concatenation operators (`.`) after the variables. Any decent editor should flag those sorts of errors before you even save the file.

Comment: to take Mark's 3rd point one step further, here is an example of what your query should look like: $sql = "SELECT venue FROM schedules WHERE venue = '" . $_POST['venue'] . "' && date = '" . $_POST['date'] . "' ";